# CSS: Switch position with another

Tags: css, html, stylesheet, styles

http://forums.animefushigi.com/showthread.php?161-Poll-Test

I want to switch the position of "Vote Now" and "View Poll" Results buttons

I'm having trouble figuring how what css to change to do this

*edit* oh sorry, you can Login with Test / test

Comment: This requires some kind of login to see the vote now button.

Comment: I think we need to login to see the buttons, can you post some code pls?

Comment: so you want them on the opposite side to what they currently reside?

Comment: fixed !!! login with Test/test

Comment: Test/test test/test TEST/TEST all failed. :(  has someone locked it out already!?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use css

> float:left; / float:right;

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a mild misconception than CSS can switch positions of elements arbitrarily.  It all depends on the design of the layout and its accompanying HTML.

Seeing your HTML will help!

If you knew the widths of side-by-side elements, you can position them but that's not very robust if the layout is fluid or different browser vendors or settings influence the elements widths.  Positioning can lead to nasty overlapping elements.

Floating your buttons within their container may be an option, e.g. if the buttons are float:left, they will be in their original order.  If they are float:right, their order will be reversed.  Their container will need to be floated too probably.  I'd need to see the HTML to explain it with confidence.